# Как скачать видео по blob URL на Youtube?

Tags: javascript, url, youtube, blob

Есть видео с `src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/qwerty"`
Как средствами JavaScript скачать это видео?

Comment: Для начала, как ты средствами java получил этот адрес?

Comment: @Qwertiy адрес приходит из вне.

Comment: Нет, так не годится. Этот адрес формируется там, где есть данные. Сам адрес случайный и по нему ничего получить невозможно, кроме как на той странице, которая его создала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы никак не скачаете видео именно по этой ссылке, т.к. на Youtube-разработчики удаляют доступ к файлу при помощи метода `URL.revokeObjectURL()`. Вот что об этом методе написано [в справке разработчика](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL):

> Статический метод `URL.revokeObjectURL()` освобождает URL-объект, созданный ранее при помощи `URL.createObjectURL()`.  Вызовите этот метод, когда закончите использовать URL-объект, чтобы браузер больше не предоставлял ссылку на файл.

Если бы, к примеру, ссылку на файл не удаляли, то его можно было бы скачать . В случае с Youtube ссылка получается одноразовой. Если вы перезагрузите страничку на Youtube, то увидите, что там будет новая ссылка.

Возможно, у вас возникнет вопрос "как скачать видео с Youtube по ссылке `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwerty`", но для этого вам нужно задать уже новый вопрос.

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ)))